# Flat descent and cohomology of quasicoherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Proof of fpqc descent for quasicoherent sheaves (its final part with Amitsur complex) looks really similar to proving that quasicoherent sheaves do not have cohomology on affine varieties. Is the second statement a formal consequence or is there any general theory/procedure which relates these two?

Originally asked as [Math Stack Exchange question 4415153](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415153).

Comment: The Amitsur complex for $R \to \prod_{i=1}^n R[1/f_i]$ is the Čech complex for the standard covering $\coprod_i D(f_i) \to \operatorname{Spec} R$. The proof that the Amitsur complex is fpqc-locally nilhomotopic is exactly the same as the proof that the Čech complex is Zariski-locally nilhomotopic (or I suppose this can be done stalkwise instead, like in \[Tag [01X9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01X9)\]). Of course a small argument is needed to go from Čech cohomology to cohomology, but this is standard.